# Visual Studio community 2019 cannot add cpp files to project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

[file browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWqsT.png)

[Installation details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZR6h.png)

Main problem:

- I have created a new, empty project and I want to populate it with
  pre-existing .cpp files and a header file, but the file browser does
  not allow the .cpp or .h extensions to show.

Possible cause 1:

- I think it might be the installation details

Possible cause 2:

- I have some legacy files from visual studio code

Context:

- I migrated from using VS code to VS because code somehow wasn't able
  to compile the 2 .cpp and 1 .h files my teacher gave me. I got tired
  with messing about JSON files and compilers and such and threw in the
  towel when my professor recommended the school's preferred IDE.

Comment: ***I migrated from using VS code to VS because code somehow wasn't able to compile the 2 .cpp and 1 .h files my teacher gave me*** There is a way to fix that by reading the VSCode C++ documentation. However with that said I recommend you use Visual Studio Community anyways for c++ development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Solution Explorer, right-click on your **project** and select Add → Existing Item... (You have probably clicked on the solution itself rather than on the project.)

Comment: Thanks! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sit.